# TT X-trader API

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading

Does anyone know how to query TT X-trader API to figure out if an order ( given order site-key ) is in the market?

Currently I'm doing a lookup on the **`siteKey`**, which should return an order object.

However, if the order is no longer in the market, an exception is thrown, which in **`MATLAB`** can be caught with a `try|catch` syntax.

```
try 
    ...

    ttOrderSet = xtrdr.OrderSet;
    ttOrderObj = ttOrderSet.SiteKeyLookupEx( siteKey );

    ... % order is    in the market

catch
    ... % Order isn't in the market

end
```

Problem with this mechanism is that I have bugs elsewhere in my code that need a breakpoint and this piece of code automatically causes a breakpoint to occur, which means that it unnecesarily stops everytime I query the order.

I'm sure a function exists such that one can query whether the order is live in the market or not.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are using a "try/catch" to *query* something? And as a beginner here on Stack Overflow, please start by [reading the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Then also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yo Joachim , how does that look now?